# Zooming in unity mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, zooming, limit, pinchzoom, pinch

I'm trying to zoom in and out in my game with a zoom limit. I'm using this code to scroll and pinch but I didn't figure out how to limit the zoom distance (minzoomlimit and maxzoomlimit). I mean when the player wants to zoom in he can zoom for a certain distance and when he wants to zoom out he zoom for certain distance.

This is the code I'm using to scroll and pinch.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScrollAndPinch : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
    public Camera Camera;
    public bool Rotate;
    protected Plane Plane;
    public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the field of view in perspective mode.
    public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.5f;





    public Transform Map;

    float distance;

    float MaxDistance = 37063.57f; /*= new Vector3(-3724.8f, 34576.9f, -4562.5f);*/
    float MinDistance = 123302.2f; /*= new Vector3(-18149.0f, 180315.6f, -73023.5f);*/

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Camera == null)
            Camera = Camera.main;
        Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;

    }

    private void Update()
    {

        //Update Plane
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
            Plane.SetNormalAndPosition(transform.up, transform.position);

        var Delta1 = Vector3.zero;
        var Delta2 = Vector3.zero;

        //Scroll
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            Delta1 = PlanePositionDelta(Input.GetTouch(0));
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                Camera.transform.Translate(Delta1, Space.World);
        }


        //Pinch
        if (Input.touchCount >= 2)
        {
            var pos1 = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            var pos2 = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(1).position);
            var pos1b = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(0).position - Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition);
            var pos2b = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(1).position - Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition);

            //calc zoom
            var zoom = Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2) /
                       Vector3.Distance(pos1b, pos2b);
            //Debug.Log(zoom);
            //edge case
            if (zoom == 0 || zoom > 10)
                return;

            //Move cam amount the mid ray
            // Camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.fieldOfView, MinDistance, MaxDistance);
            distance = Vector3.Distance(Camera.transform.position, Map.position);
            Camera.transform.position = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(pos1, Camera.transform.position, 1/zoom);




            if (Rotate && pos2b != pos2)

            Camera.transform.RotateAround(pos1, Plane.normal, Vector3.SignedAngle(pos2 - pos1, pos2b - pos1b, Plane.normal));







        }

    }

    protected Vector3 PlanePositionDelta(Touch touch)
    {
        //not moved
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Moved)
            return Vector3.zero;

        //delta
        var rayBefore = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position - touch.deltaPosition);
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayBefore, out var enterBefore) && Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayBefore.GetPoint(enterBefore) - rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        //not on plane
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    protected Vector3 PlanePosition(Vector2 screenPos)
    {
        //position
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(screenPos);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.up);
    }
#endif
}
```

Any Help please thank you :D .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is quite simple, all you have to do is add this piece of code in your update function;

```
void Update()
{
         if(cam.fieldOfView < minimunDistance)
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = minimunDistance;
         }
         else
         if(cam.fieldOfView > maxDistance)
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = maxDistance;
         }
}
```

Alternatively, I have a script for Pinch and Zoom that should work in touch input devices and also with mouse scroll wheel;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PinchAndZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    float MouseZoomSpeed = 15.0f;
    float TouchZoomSpeed = 0.1f;
    float ZoomMinBound = 0.1f;
    float ZoomMaxBound = 179.9f;
    Camera cam;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchSupported)
        {
            // Pinch to zoom
            if (Input.touchCount == 2)
            {

                // get current touch positions
                Touch tZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
                Touch tOne = Input.GetTouch(1);
                // get touch position from the previous frame
                Vector2 tZeroPrevious = tZero.position - tZero.deltaPosition;
                Vector2 tOnePrevious = tOne.position - tOne.deltaPosition;

                float oldTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance (tZeroPrevious, tOnePrevious);
                float currentTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance (tZero.position, tOne.position);

                // get offset value
                float deltaDistance = oldTouchDistance - currentTouchDistance;
                Zoom (deltaDistance, TouchZoomSpeed);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
            Zoom(scroll, MouseZoomSpeed);
        }



         if(cam.fieldOfView < ZoomMinBound) 
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = 0.1f;
         }
         else
         if(cam.fieldOfView > ZoomMaxBound ) 
         {
             cam.fieldOfView = 179.9f;
         }
    }

    void Zoom(float deltaMagnitudeDiff, float speed)
    {

        cam.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * speed;
        // set min and max value of Clamp function upon your requirement
        cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(cam.fieldOfView, ZoomMinBound, ZoomMaxBound);
    }
}
```

Comment: epic answer
but why do u clamp it twice? once in end of update with if statements and one in zoom method with Mathf.Clamp?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the Unity Editor if you're previewing the playing of your game with the device simulator then retrieving the scrollwheel axis will always result in 0. Thought I'd leave this here to save someone like me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Variant that works in the game simulator. Just hold your mouse in the same place for long enough and it'll start zooming in/out.

```
    private float zoomSpeed = 0.1f;
    private float ZoomMinBound = 0.1f;
    private float ZoomMaxBound = 179.9f;
    private Camera cam;

    private bool zooming;
    private float startHoldTime;
    private float holdTime = 0f;
    private const float REQD_HOLD_ZOOM_TIME = 0.5f;
    private bool zoomIn = true;
    private Vector3 lastMousePosition;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
            if (Input.touchSupported)
            {
                // Pinch to zoom
                if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                {

                    // get current touch positions
                    Touch tZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
                    Touch tOne = Input.GetTouch(1);
                    // get touch position from the previous frame
                    Vector2 tZeroPrevious = tZero.position - tZero.deltaPosition;
                    Vector2 tOnePrevious = tOne.position - tOne.deltaPosition;

                    float oldTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance (tZeroPrevious, tOnePrevious);
                    float currentTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance (tZero.position, tOne.position);

                    // get offset value
                    float deltaDistance = oldTouchDistance - currentTouchDistance;
                    Zoom (deltaDistance, zoomSpeed);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float scroll = 0;

                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    if(Input.mousePosition == lastMousePosition)
                    {
                        if(zooming)
                        {
                            holdTime = Time.time - startHoldTime;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            startHoldTime = Time.time;
                            zooming = true;
                        }

                        if(holdTime > REQD_HOLD_ZOOM_TIME)
                        {
                            if (zoomIn)
                            {
                                scroll = 1;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                scroll = -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                        zooming = false;
                    }
                    
                }
                else if(zooming)
                {
                    zoomIn = !zoomIn;
                    scroll = 0;
                    zooming = false;
                }

                if(scroll != 0)
                {
                    Zoom(scroll, zoomSpeed);
                }
            }
    }
```

As I mentioned in a comment: "Unfortunately, in the Unity Editor if you're previewing the playing of your game with the device simulator then retrieving the scrollwheel axis will always result in 0."

So, instead I only use the button 0 event since it works in the simulator.